# Apache HTTP Filter/Logging

Tags: apache, http

I am using IBM HTTP Server 6.1 / Apache 2.0.47. I would like to pull a specific piece of data out of all requests coming through the HTTP server and if it exists log the found data along with the target URL. It needs to be as efficient as possible.

Is a filter appropriate or a handler? 
Does a filter/handler exist that I can configure and use as is or do I need to write something? How do I configure, or write this?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe there are some modules for forensic logging that may be able to do this. But this is a server security / config question that would probably be better asked on Serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **mod_security** apache module , which have a good audit log tool *SecAuditLog* (log all headers), that you can declench by http status. You'll find as well fine filters, that will maybe fits your needs.

And do not hesitate to ask servfault gurus on that.